# MacOS underestimates battery life on replacement battery

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I recently replaced the battery in my late 2011 MacBook Pro, and the battery seems to do fine except that it will drop very quickly from about 75% down to 2% and then continue to work for quite a while (I haven't timed it but probably close to an hour if not more of normal use).

What could cause this, and how might I fix it, so that it shows a more reasonable battery life estimate?

It's a little irritating having to guess at how much time I have left before it sleeps.

---

coconutBattery says:

- Current Charge: 114 mAh (2%)

Note: this hasn't changed from 114 in the 15 (edit: 20) or so minutes since I first checked.

- Full Charge Capacity: 5752 mAh
- Design Capacity: 6900 mAh
- Manufacture date: 2015-06-24
- Loadcycles: 13
- macOS Battery status: Good
- Discharging with: 12.15 Watts
- Manufacturer: Simplo
- Battery failure: Yes

That last one makes me a little nervous. What does "Battery failure: Yes" mean?

Comment: What does macOS report as the battery condition? What does coconutBattery say?

Comment: @JMY1000 where does macOS report the battery's condition?

Comment: I'm running high sierra if that matters

Comment: Maybe the replacement battery is broken?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do a NVRAM and SMC reset (in that order). Before following the steps below, ensure you have no external hardware connected and that you're using the **built-in keyboard**.

**Reset the NVRAM**

Reset the NVRAM on your MBP as follows:

1. **Shut down your machine.** That is, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys. You have to make sure you press these keys **before** the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your MBP reboots again and you here the startup chime.
4. Let go of the keys and let your MBP reboot normally.

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, time zone information, etc).

**Reset the SMC**

There's a couple of ways you can reset the SMC on your MBP, however I prefer the following steps:

1. Shut down your MBP
2. Keep the power cable **plugged in**
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the **left** side of the keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button

After resetting both the NVRAM and SMC, use your computer to determine how well macOS is reporting the remaining battery life.

**Battery Condition**

To view what macOS has determined as the battery's condition, hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key and click on the battery icon in the menu bar. You'll now see the *condition* reported at the top of the drop-down menu that appears.

**coconutBattery**

If you haven't already, I recommend you download and install [coconutBattery](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) <sup>1</sup>. It provides a whole heap of information that you'll find useful!

<sup>1</sup> Note: I am not affiliated with coconutBattery in any way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to 'train' the Mac on a new battery, so it resets its estimates.

iFixit includes these [battery calibration](https://www.ifixit.com/Wiki/Battery_Calibration) instructions with all their battery replacement kits & how-tos

> 1. Charge it to 100%, and keep charging it for at least two more hours.
> 2. Unplug your laptop and use it normally to drain the battery.
> 3. Save your work when you see the low battery warning.
> 4. Keep your laptop on until it goes to sleep due to low battery.
> 5. Wait at least five hours, then charge your laptop uninterrupted to 100%.